# getTile("Philippines") for MODIS R package likely bug

Tags: r, geospatial, r-modis

Using R MODIS package from CRAN (version 1.1)

Code:

```
#Works#
library(MODIS)
getTile("Maldives")

#Doesn't Work#
getTile("Philippines")
```

I get error: Error in createPolygonsComment(p) :
rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 1 #

Yes, I checked that the Philippines is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the developer:

https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS/issues/34

This should be fixed in the dev version of modis package on github now.

Cheers.

Comment: Fixed on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODIS/index.html) as of **MODIS** version 1.1.2.